# How do I send confirmation emails to multiple respondent addresses when entries are submitted in Cognito Forms?

Tags: email, cognito-forms

I have a need to email a form submission to two respondent addresses each time the form is submitted.  In a perfect world I would be able to place two email fields on the form and select both in the mail To field on the submissions page.  This doesn't look possible.

I see in the forums that this should be possible by placing a semicolon between the addresses and using a single email field.  However the validation for the email field rejects the address when you use the semicolon as a separator.  Is there another way to do this that I am missing?

Comment: I closed this question as it looks like a support ticket, not as a practical, detailed question. See [tour], [ask], [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4502/88163)

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com). Unlike the notification email, you can only have one recipient for a confirmation email. However, we are planning to provide support for multiple email notification configurations in the near future. You can follow our progress on this feature over on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/iXlwst3H/128-conditional-notifications).

Comment: Support for multiple email notifications and confirmations is now live.  Just add two confirmation email notifications and select the correct respondent email address field for each.